# takefocus = NO fails to prevent tkinter.ttk.Notebook tabs from taking focus

Tags: python, tkinter, ttk

In the following example, I have set the Notebook to not take focus, so that its tabs get skipped over while navigating from widget to widget using the shortcuts supported by `enable_traversal()`. This mostly works, but not entirely. If a tab is already being displayed (but doesn't have focus), pressing its `<Alt-Key>` underline-style shortcut gives it focus. How can I prevent this?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

nb = ttk.Notebook(root, takefocus = NO)
nb.enable_traversal()

f1 = Frame(nb)
b1a = Button(f1, text = 'Charlie')
b1b = Button(f1, text = 'Delta')

f2 = Frame(nb)
b2a = Button(f2, text = 'Echo')
b2b = Button(f2, text = 'Foxtrot')

b1a.pack()
b1b.pack()

b2a.pack()
b2b.pack()

f1.pack()
f2.pack()

nb.pack()

nb.add(f1, text = 'Alpha', underline = 0)
nb.add(f2, text = 'Bravo', underline = 0)
```

Comment: Please read the [docs](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Notebook.html) on what takefocus takes effect. It prevents the notebook itself from taking focus through focus traversal. Not the tabs.

Comment: To be clear, I want to prevent the tab labels at the top of the Notebook from taking focus, and not the Frames that each tab contains. I tried to set  each tab to not take focus like so: `nb.tab(0)['takefocus'] = NO` However, I suspect that this sets options on the Frame contained by the tab, and not the tab's label. Since non-visible Widgets default to not take focus, no change was observed.

Comment: The tabs itself should be affected by the notebook itself beeing set to `takefocus = NO`. The frames inside are a different matter, but the tabctrl itself as part of the basic notebook should act like that. <b>BUT</b>: the option only takes what is there if i am not mistaken. so you should set it after adding the last tab to it.

Answer (score 0):

Why then add `underline=0`? Remove that piece of code in both the lines. Also, add another argument `takefocus=False` while adding the tabs. And remove `takefocus` when you are creating the notebook.

Comment: I added the underline arguments because I want `<Alt-Key>`-style direct access to the tabs. As I mentioned, the `takefocus = NO` argument partially prevents the tab labels from taking focus (i.e. while cycling through widgets by pressing Tab). Removing takefocus from the notebook removes this desired effect.  
Adding takefocus = NO to the nb.add() method call seems to set that option for the Frame in the tab, and not the tab label. Is there a way that the tab label itself can be accessed?